# Remove Currency Symbol

Tags: crystal-reports

My selection formula it works fine, but it shows a `$` symbol before amounts. How can I remove this?

```
if {tblComparativeBalance.iAcctLevel} - {@@highest_level} = 0 
then if Sum ({tblComparativeBalance.mBalance_amt0}, {tblComparativeBalance.sAccount_cd}) > 0 
         then ToText(Sum ({tblComparativeBalance.mBalance_amt0}, {tblComparativeBalance.sAccount_cd}),2)
         else  "(" + ToText(abs(Sum ({tblComparativeBalance.mBalance_amt0}, {tblComparativeBalance.sAccount_cd})),2) + ")"
else ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to right-click on this formula field on your layout, then choose `Format Field...`

In the number tab, un-check the `Display Currency Symbol`, then click `OK`

But since in your formula you are converting it to string, you have to edit your formula to the following:

```
ToText(Sum ({tblComparativeBalance.mBalance_amt0},{tblComparativeBalance.sAccount_cd}),2, "")
```

The last parameter is the Character of the Currency symbol, so in this case you are setting it to empty, means no currency symbol.

Same thing is applied to the else formula.

```
"(" + ToText(abs(Sum ({tblComparativeBalance.mBalance_amt0}, {tblComparativeBalance.sAccount_cd})),2, "") + ")"
```

Comment: Formula converts it into string. When I right click on formula field on my layout click on format field the number tab is not exist. There i found common, border, font, paragraph and hyperlink tabs

Comment: Refresh your report, or even remove the formula, then re-place it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove it from Strings, you can use:

```
REPLACE( {yourStringHere} ,"$","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to number first, then text:

`````
ToText(ToNumber({YOUR_VALUE}))````
`````